Laravel temp attributes inside 'with' and 'each' together
I'm trying to use Laravel each method inside a with in my query builder but the attribute I'm adding inside my each method does not persist to the collection. My attribute does show when I dd($task); inside the each method.
$projects =
    Project::with(['tasks' => function($query) {
        $query
        ->whereBetween('start_date', ['2024-04-21', '2024-04-28'])
        ->orWhereBetween('end_date', ['2024-04-21', '2024-04-28'])
        ->each(function($task, $key) {
            //if statements here 
            $task->test = 'test';
            $task->setAttribute('date', $task->end_date);

            // dd($task); <- this returns the 'test' and 'date' attributes above
        });
    }])
    ->status(['Active', 'Scheduled'])->sortByDesc('last_status.start_date');
// dd($projects->first()->tasks->first()); <- this is missing the 'test' and 'date' attributes from above


TL;DR
You can't use each inside a with because it's not actually returning the models, it's just using the query and combining data later.
Jump to the workaround section below for a potential solution.
How "with" works
Eloquent uses with to allow nested relationships to be returned as a hierarchy. This is different to a join query where the attributes of both models are returned as one object containing all the attributes
Behind the scenes Eloquent performs separate queries for each of the with relationships, then builds the object hierarchy in memory before returning the result.
In your case there will be a
select *
from projects

followed by
select *
from tasks
where project_id in (1,2,3 ...) -- all the project.id values
and ... -- your additional where clauses

The projects collection is then merged with their related tasks using the foreign key in the task objects.
In contrast, each is a callback applied to all the models returned by the query after it has been executed. By using each on the query inside a with it's forces Eloquent to execute it immediately as well as return the query for later execution; but appears to ignore the each when building the object hierarchy.
In testing this on my local project I see the second query - the one inside the with closure - executed twice even though it's only needed once to get all the tasks associated with the project.
Workaround
To add attributes to the task models you can perform separate queries and combine the results.
// Get all the projects
$projects = Project::all();

// Get tasks for these projects and add attributes.
$projectIds = $projects->pluck('id');
$tasks = Task::whereIn('project_id', $projectIds)
  ->get()
  ->each(function ($task) {
      $task->test = 'test';
  })->groupBy('project_id');

// Combine projects and tasks
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $project->tasks = $tasks[$project->id] ?? collect();
}



Thank you @Tony! This looks very promising and I'm starting to implement it. Thanks for the explanations. My only worry is the network requests im creating here and how this will impact my speed. This gets called quite often, every DOM change, while the end user is adjusting a gantt chart. I will investigate and report. Thanks for your help!

@dfeva you can optimise the queries a bit by not selecting every column of the table if you don't need it. Add select(...) to the Project & Task queries when getting the data. You could also make speed improvements by adding the additional attributes in the SQL query, rather than looping over the returned items, but that would depend on what you actually need to add.
